# How to permanently logout the user from my asp.net core application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am new in ASP.NET CORE, so please understand me.

I am currently developing a Login and Logout Process for my application in .Net Core.

My problems are:

1. After Log Out, the session is not abandon nor deleted.
2. After Log Out, If I click the back button of the browser, it will be redirected to the page where you trigger the logout button.

These are my ideas but I don't know how to do it.

1. If the user Logout, the session will be deleted and abandon.
2. After the user clicks the Logout and then click the back button of the browser, I want to show the `Confirm Form Resubmission` and Redirect him to Login where he can login their Account.

Here is my code:

**LoginController.cs**

```cs
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult Login(LoginModel userLogin)
{
    ILogicInterface<UserInput, SystemResult> dbLogic = new LoginLogic();
    UserInput userInput = new UserInput();
    userInput[typeof(LoginModel).FullName] = userLogin;
    SystemResult systemResult = dbLogic.DoProcess(userInput);
    bool userExist = systemResult.ResultCode
                     == SystemResult.RESULT_CODE_SUCCESS;

    if (userExist)
    {
       LoginInfomation loginInfomation = 
       systemResult[typeof(LoginInfomation).FullName] as LoginInfomation;

       HttpContext.Session.SetString("userInfo"
               , JsonConvert.SerializeObject(loginInfomation));
       Claim[] claims = new[] {
           new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, loginInfomation.E_mail)
           , new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role
           , AccountInformation.GetRole(loginInfomation.AccountInfo.roleID)) 
       };

       ClaimsIdentity identity = 
        new(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

       AuthenticationHttpContextExtensions.SignInAsync(HttpContext
                     , new ClaimsPrincipal(identity));
       return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
    else
    {
       ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty
                   , "The specified email or password is incorrect.");
       return View(userLogin);
    }
}
```

**HomeController.cs**

```cs
public IActionResult Logout()
{
    AuthenticationHttpContextExtensions.SignOutAsync(HttpContext
           , CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    return RedirectToAction("Login", "Login");
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```cs
services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

services.AddSession(options =>
{
   options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
   options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
});

services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options => {
         options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
         options.LoginPath = new PathString("/Login/Login");
});
```

Can someone help me to achieve the ideas listed above. Thank you and Regards,

Comment: Pretty sure signout (with auth cookie) worked the way you intended when I wrote this post. Maybe some hints in there? https://blog.elmah.io/cookie-authentication-with-social-providers-in-asp-net-core/

Comment: @ThomasArdal , Thank you Sir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the customHeaders in in web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Cache-Control" value="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, pre-check=0, post-check=0, max-age=0, s-maxage=0" />
    <add name="Pragma" value="no-cache" />
    <add name="Expires" value="0" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer, but I think this is for .Net Framework not for .Net Core

Comment: Hi, Thank your answer. it gives me an idea what to search and found this one. `[ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]` HAHA now i can code in peace.

Answer (score 0):

Please Try Once this

In Startup.cs

```
 services.AddSession(options =>
 {
    options.Cookie.Name = "ExampleSession";
    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
    options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
});
```

In Controller

```
     public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
     {
        try
        {
            await HttpContext.SignOutAsync("ExampleSession");
            return RedirectToAction("Login", "Login");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
     }
```

Comment: Hi Sir, thank you for your response. But the `HttpContext.Current` was removed in ASP.NE Core, maybe that would work in .Net Framework but in my case, it would be impossible to use it.

Comment: please try the above code i have changed now to .net core

Comment: I am very thankful for your responds sir. but still not working.